# Are there any drawbacks to using this method as a conditional?

Tags: python

I've been working in pygame a lot, and for a couple of conditionals in one of my games, I used the following:

```
if character.direction in ["left, right"]:
       #some code
```

Rather than

```
if character.direction == "left" or character.direction == "right":
       #some code
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing this? I understand that the implementation is context-specific, but I showed a friend and he said it looked stupid. Just wondering if anyone had any input. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `in ["left", "right"]`. As shown, that's a list containing only one string item. But with that fixed, it's not only fine, it's better—more concise, more readable, and more maintainable due to the lack of repetition.

Comment: Please only use tags to characterize the *question you are asking*, not simply to describe the overall task you are trying to get done. A Python expert can help with writing Python code, but there is no reason why an expert in the Pygame library would have a special insight into how to use `if` statements or how to test the content of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The first is *not* equivalent to the second, as `"t, r"`, for instance, would be *in* `"left, right"`.

The following would make perfect sense:

```
if character.direction in ["left", "right"]:
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks for catching that. Edited my post to better reflect my question haha.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in ways that invalidate existing answers.